# Java Read Text file with condition

Tags: java, split, bufferedreader

I'm just wondering if there's a way to read a text file and skip a line with specific string.

For example (test1.txt):

```
test0,orig,valid,nice
test1,input,of,ol,[www]
test2,[eee],oa,oq
test3,wa,eee,string,int
test4,asfd,eee,[tsddas],wwww
```

Expected output :

```
test0,orig,valid,nice
test3,wa,eee,string,int
```

I already have this code :

```
String line;
String test[];

try{
    LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(file2,"UTF-8");
    while(it.hasNext()){                    
        line = it.nextLine();                    
        test = StringUtils.split(line,(",")); 
    }
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Some way other than just putting in an `if` statement?

Comment: If you're reading `csv` you may want to use a `csv` parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
line = it.nextLine();

if (line.contains("specific string")) continue;

test = StringUtils.split(line,(","));
```

Why are you using StringUtils to split a line? The `String` class supports a `split(...)` method.

I suggest you read the String API for basic functionality.

Comment: I'm using StringUtils for faster reading, because I'm reading a million lines of text. So how can I remove the line that contains "[".

Comment: Oh sweet, I figured out now how the line removed. Thanks for this one!

Comment: `I'm using StringUtils for faster reading,` - StringUtils is not reading the data. It is splitting the data. I don't know if StringUtils if faster than the String.split() method or not, but for speed you should look at the `StringTokenizer`. It is fast because it is very simple.

Answer (score 0):

You could also make use of the Java 8 Streaming API. It allows all this rather easily.

```java
final List<String[]> rows = Files.lines(Paths.get(file2), "UTF-8")
        .filter(l -> !l.contains("["))
        .map(l -> l.split(","))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to do it fast and don't want to run into any issues, you should also think about using an existing CSV library. A nice example is the Apache Commons CSV library (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).